# Refreshing web page in real time in sails.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js

In my project I am using sails.js. From test1.ejs I am calling a web service which in turn calls another ejs(test2.ejs) using res.view(). 
Now android user is inputting some values which affects the database and needs to reflect on the web page in real time. I am not able to figure out how this can be achieved using sails.js. 
Also I need to  even show the android user response and at the same time refresh the web page. In short I want a dynamic UI like share market where any changes on the server is reflected on the front end. 
Will I need to use anything else like angularjs?

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript Interface if I understand your problem right.

You should create the class like this:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

After this you should connect this interface to your webview like this:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

Now you can call Java code from JS like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

Or call JS code from Java like this:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.showAndroidToast(\"Hello, World!\")");
```

More info is available here: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: thnx for the reply but the problem I am facing is how to automatically refresh the web page. The mobile app can also be replaced by another web page.

Comment: Ohh... Sorry... I didn't look at the tags and thought about Android :)